# Error run Desktop libgdx when import with Gradle

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, gradle, libgdx, build.gradle

I've imported a Libgdx projecto using Gradle.
After I've followed these instructions: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA#running-your-project

But, it returns the next bug when trying launch the desktop version:

(*class Bootstrap is the main class of the core)

> Information:Gradle: Executing tasks: [:desktop:assemble, :core:assemble]
>
> Information:18/06/2015 10:29 - Compilation completed with 3 errors and 1 warning in 5s 37ms
>
> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':desktop:compileJava'.
>
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>   Warning:Gradle: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
>
> D:\workspace\delee\desktop\src\com\josemwarrior\delee\desktop\DesktopLauncher.java
>
> Error:(5, 30) Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class Bootstrap
>
> Error:(12, 28) Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class Bootstrap

I'm using Android Studio 1.2.2

And when I execute the "Make" button, gives me the next error:

> D:\workspace\delee\desktop\src\com\josemwarrior\delee\desktop\DesktopLauncher.java
>
> Error:(5, 30) error: cannot find symbol class Bootstrap
>
> Error:(12, 28) error: cannot find symbol class Bootstrap
>   1 warning
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':desktop:compileJava'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Answer (score 5):

Just select Build->Clean, and Build->Rebuild project, and all gone fine